# Is it possible to use Aggregate functions in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, mapping, mybatis

I am a newbie to MyBatis. As per my knowledge every column is mapped to a property value while retrieving data from the database. So is it possible to use aggregate functions using MyBatis. To what property we will map the results? I have searched it everywhere But can't find any details about the usage of aggregate functions with MyBatis. If anyone can help, please.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. As you say "every column is mapped to a property". However, that refers to a column of the result set, not a table. The result set column may already be an aggregated column.

Comment: @TheImpaler Ok. Suppose if we have  column named email in our database table called instructor. Then I want to execute a SQL query as follows 

///SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS counts FROM instructor GROUP BY email;///

So in our ResultSet we will be having 2 columns, one called email and another counts. So now the question is how can we map these 2 columns. I don't have a count property in my Instructor Pojo Class.

Comment: If you don't want to create another POJO, you can always retrieve the result as a list of `java.util.Map<String, Object>`, that is a  `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you for the response. I have tried it. But When I try to print the keys/values in the Map within List that is returned, I am getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Every column of the result set is mapped to a property. Therefore, it's just a matter of producing a SQL statement that does that.

For example:

```
<resultMap id="regionProfit" type="app.RegionProfitVO">
  <result property="region" column="region" />
  <result property="cnt" column="cnt" />
  <result property="profit" column="profit" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getRegionProfit" resultMap="regionProfit">
  select
    region,
    count(sales) as cnt,
    sum(revenue) - sum(expenses) as profit 
  from sales
  group by region
</select>
```

Now, in the Java code you could do something like:

```
List<RegionProfitVO> rp = sqlSession.selectList("getRegionProfit");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :) 
Can you also show how to retrieve these results in the main code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create another POJO, you can always retrieve the result as a list of java.util.Map<String, Object> but use **resultType="hashmap"** in mapper.xml file for that select query